# Why does Firefox show seconds for time input with minute as smallest unit?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

### Problem

Firefox (v65.0.1 on OS X) is behaving strangely for me when it comes to inputs of type [time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time). Even if such an input is configured to use a [step](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Using_the_step_attribute) value of a minute (which is the default), and as such doesn't deal with seconds, it shows a section for inputting seconds (although it's disabled for user input). Even the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) of time type inputs says that the input will only display a seconds input area if the step property is less than 60 seconds.

Is this a bug in Firefox, as it would seem to me? Is there any way of working around it?

The below screenshot shows how the input is rendered for me in Firefox, even though the step is 60 and seconds should as such not be available.

[image: screenshot]

### Demonstration

The following provides a time input and a piece of text that will display the time input into the field. This works on f.ex. Chrome, but on Firefox it doesn't because the `input` event never fires (because of the seconds area of the input, which you can't even fill).

```css
const elem = document.getElementById('time-input')
const displayElem = document.getElementById('time-display')
elem.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const {value} = e.target
  displayElem.textContent = value
})
```

```html
<input id="time-input" type="time">
<p>Current time is: <span id="time-display">n/a</a></p>
```

Comment: Your pen works fine for me (if I add the step as the docs suggest)

Comment: Please don't post executable code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. All you need to do is create a "code snippet", right here in your question. This makes it simpler for everyone to run your code and easier for us to move it into answers.

Comment: @ScottMarcus But I included code snippets as you ask? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: No, you didn't include "snippets", you include raw code, which can't be run directly right here in your question. I've edited your question to take that code and turn it into a snippet. We shouldn't have to leave Stack Overflow just to run your code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Ah OK, I guess I'm not familiar with the code snippets feature.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Where do the docs suggest to configure the step property and how? The step is by default 60 seconds, if I try to configure the step explicitly, nothing changes, in that the seconds area of the input is still present (and disabled). Are you using FF v65?

Comment: When you are creating your question, you have a toolbar available to you for formatting. On that toolbar is an icon that looks like this: `{}`. This button creates an environment similar to a Pen or a Fiddle for you to set your code up in.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Nope, those bracket's `{}` is for code formatting, the `<>` on the other hand is for a snippet

Comment: @LGSon Yes, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: **Don't mistake the `AM / PM` placeholder dashes for seconds input placeholders!**

It just dawned on me what you are seeing in that image you posted in your question. Those dashes are the `AM/PM` placeholders.

To remove those placeholders (in FF), the browser locale is used to determine if `am/pm` are used. If the locale is set to a 24hr locale, then time will be in 24hr format and you will lose the `am/pm` selector.

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('time-input')
const displayElem = document.getElementById('time-display')
elem.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const {value} = e.target
  displayElem.textContent = value
})

const elem2 = document.getElementById('time-input2')
const displayElem2 = document.getElementById('time-display2')
elem2.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const {value} = e.target
  displayElem2.textContent = value
})
```

```html
<input id="time-input" type="time" step="59">
<p>Current time is: <span id="time-display">n/a</span></p>
<br>
<input id="time-input2" type="time">
<p>Current time is: <span id="time-display2">n/a</span></p>
```

Comment: You've misunderstood the question. The problem is that I'm seeing an area for inputting seconds in FF (and not Chrome f.ex.), even though the step size is 60 and I do not want to input seconds.

Comment: I've added a second input. Again, it works flawlessly for me in FF 65.

Comment: D'oh, you're right! It never dawned on me it would be am/pm selection. Partially because I've configured my computer to use a 24-hour clock and Chrome, my main browser, goes with that automatically.

I also wonder if this might be considered bad UX by FF, since my user who reported this to me also thought you were supposed to input seconds. Any way, problem solved, thanks!

Comment: funny how we look right past things some times. That's why I was wrong with my answer initially too! I do believe it is a bad UI/UX thing for sure!

Comment: My OS locals are set to 24 hrs. Yet Firefox is stiil showing the AM/PM input place holder. How can I remove those placeholders in FF? I'm using Win 11 + FF 104.0.1 (64-bit)